# TFS - Creating a Branch from Label, Impact on shared projects

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, branching-and-merging

Our TFS Source Control is setup like this:

1. TFS Project

   - Solutions
   - - WebApp1Solution
   - - WebApp2Solution
   - Libraries
   - - SharedLibrary1
   - Web Applications
   - - WebApp1
   - - WebApp2

When I open solution WebApp1Solution, it loads my workspace with projects from Libraries and Web Applications folder.

I would like to suspend my current workspace environment for both web apps and all shared libraries and start working on a specific version of this code from an earlier label (our last deployment). We do not have any branching as of yet.

From what I've read, I think these are my options:
1. Shelve pending changes on the solution and get the specific label version of the solution. **What would happen when I check any changes back in?**
2. Create a branch in Source Control from the specific label version.  **Would I have to create the branch on all of the folders in the different locations? How would I switch back and forth between my current code and new branch code?**

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I would recommend against your current source control structure. Sharing code between products is a primary cause of quality erosion and elevated bug counts. Build separately and sharing binary output through NuGet us preferable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a branch at your `TFS Project` folder into a development folder. You should actually be doing this normally for all of your development. Your mainline branch should never contain anything except for your production deployable codebase. You should always be able to get latest of your mainline and build  and run as the production end product.

All developers/teams of developers should have their own TFS folder where they can branch from mainline, make changes, test, etc... then once it has passed all approvals, merge it to mainline and destroy your devline.

As for "switching" your branch is a separate folder from your mainline. You can open both at the same time in different instances of Visual Studio, just like opening two solutions at once. Branching creates a copy of the folder/solution/project structure from the point of your branch. Then when you merge it back it reports differences and attempts to merge. If there are conflicts you will be prompted to review and resolve them. Most of the time TFS does a good job at auto-resolving, but I always carefully review all conflicts before selecting a method of resolution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I created the branch on the root folder and now I have the two versions side-by-side! I run the web apps using local iis, using a virtual directory which I publish into.
When I publish the branch into the directory, it is having trouble finding the appPool.config file now. Namely, I'm getting this error:

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007B) for the line
Microsoft.Web.Administration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection(null, null, "system.applicationHost/sites");

Comment: You may have to fiddle around with your `applicationhost.config` file for iisexpress if you are using that. If you are using IIS, I believe you will need to modify the site config to point at the location of your dev branch (or create a new site for dev). I prefer using iisexpress for dev work as you can fairly quickly switch or modify a site using the config file.